# Can't click action link

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a page with multiple rows that each have a link, "Add Tenant Info" but I can't seem to click it in a way that would be unique to each row.  I have been able to select take actions with

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[class*='sf-with-ul']"));
```

Here is the HTML of the section:

```
<tr class="false sub_row data_row highlight" id="spreadsheet_row_7117098" style="">
    <td style="background-color: rgb(232, 245, 209);">Tenant 1 Name</td>
    <td style="background-color: rgb(232, 245, 209);"><a class="action-link">Add Tenant Info</a></td>
    <td style="text-align: center; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; background-color: rgb(232, 245, 209);"> <span></span> </td>
    <td style="background-color: rgb(232, 245, 209);"><a class="action-link">Add Lease</a></td>
    <td style="width: 84px; padding: 0px; background-color: rgb(232, 245, 209);">
        <div style="">
            <ul class="sf-menu sf-js-enabled sf-arrows">
                <li><a class="sf-with-ul">Take&nbsp;Actions</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a class="action-link">Add Tenant Info</a></li>
                        <li><a class="action-link">Tenant Screening Center</a></li>
                        <li><a class="action-link">Delete Tenant</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I am using chrome driver and selenium 3.8.1

Edit:

Navigate to this site simplifyem.com

Log in with

```
user: stackoverflow@gmail.com 
pass: password
```

Then navigate to http://www.simplifyem.com/tenant_management/overview

I want to click on the "Add Tenant Info" but I need to iterate over all of them and click each one.

Comment: Which "Add Tenant Info" link are you trying to click? The first or second? Is there only one tenant per page? If you could share a link to the page it would help provide a better answer.

Comment: Navigate to this site https://www.simplifyem.com    Log in with user: stackoverflow@gmail.com  pass: password.     Then navigate to this page https://www.simplifyem.com/tenant_management/overview/   I want to click on the "Add Tenant Info" but i need to click each on.  kinda iterate over it

Comment: That helps a lot... thanks. I posted an answer that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a different xpath?
You can try doing something like:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='sf-with-ul']"));
```

Chrome driver: 2.33.5

Selenium: 3.4

Chrome browser 62.0

Comment: yeah  I have, but it wont find the element at all.  I keep getting an element not found error.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `By.linkText("Add Tenant Info")`. I tried it and it worked just fine.

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.linkText("Add Tenant Info"));
System.out.println(links.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

How about thisc:

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td/a[@class='action-link' and contains(text(),'Add Tenant Info')]"));
for (int x=0; x<links.size; x++) { 
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//td/a[@class='action-link' and contains(text(),'Add Tenant Info')])[x]")).click();
   //do other stuff
   //go back to original page
}
```

Remember that you have to go back to the original page to click on the links.
Also, you can't just iterate over the list of webelements you got before because by clicking on the link and navigating to a different page, then you are basically expiring the web elements you got. And thus when you come back to the original page, and try clicking on the web elements in the list, it will say that the element has expired.

Edited: Just checked the web app you provided

Answer (score 0):

As per the `HTML` of the `URL` in your question there are multiple `Add Tenant Info` links present. To iterate over all of them and click each one you can use the following code block :

```
List<WebElement> Add_Tenant_Info = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='table_view']//tbody//tr[@class='false sub_row data_row' or @class='false sub_row data_row highlight']//a[contains(.,'Add Tenant Info')]"));
for(int i=0; i<Add_Tenant_Info.size();i++)
{
    //Click on any Add Tenant Info link through index "i"
    Add_Tenant_Info.get(i).click();
}
```