# How to click css selector by text

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to click on this

```
<a class="action-link">Add Another Tenant</a>
```

But there is alot of action-link on the page.  So how can I select this by "add another tenant"

This is what I have so far:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[class*='action-link']")).click();
```

Comment: if there are a lot of anchor elements that have a `class` attribute of `action-link` then your selector `a[class*='action-link']` is not specific enough, can you show the surrounding elements? also, in the worst case, you can get the full `Xpath` and use that.

Comment: Do you not have the ability to change the html?  Give the link an `id='something'` attribute and then do your CSS based on ID instead of class.

Comment: A more specific CSS selector in this case would be `a.action-link`. What you have specified is a string match on class that contains "action-link" which is much less specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click an element by text using XPath instead of CSS as follows:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Add Another Tenant')]")).click();
```

Comment: @RowanSandhu come on, really. Xpath worked and link text did not. Does not make any sense judging by the error you've posted in the comment. Execute this code with the XPath 10 more times and tell me if it works 10 times in a row.

Comment: I am always wondering why do people sometimes prefer brittle and non-readable XPaths to other more elegant and straight-forward solutions.

Comment: @alecxe Here is the link to the full problem i am having https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48103210/cant-click-action-link/48103765#48103765.  If you can make this work without Xpath that would be awesome thanks!

Comment: @alecxe i don't know but i like xpath.. it's like a choice between describing where the heart actually is in comparison to some of the major organs in your body or describing the heart as in your chest.

Comment: @RowanSandhu I didn't know about this question and I posted an answer at your other one with basically what alecxe did. I coded it up and tested it and it worked fine for me. This XPath isn't going to work any more consistently than link text will in this case. If something isn't working, it's most likely due to timing issues.

Answer (score 2):

*No need for XPath expressions*, there is a specific element locator - **"link text"** ([docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html#linkText-java.lang.String-)):

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Add Another Tenant")).click();
```

Comment: This gives the error                      
    org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <a class="action-link">...</a> is not clickable at point (255, 552). Other element would receive the click: <div class="feedback_tellfriend_inner">...</div>

Comment: Yeah usually this error occurs when there's an element on top of the element you're trying to test. This solution should work as it is mostly the same as the xpath you accepted as the answer. Try waiting for the other element to be gone before doing the clicking.I don't understand why people hate on xpath so much though. It's like hating on '1=1' in SQL.

Comment: @becixb Because XPath isn't needed 99% of the time. IDs or CSS selectors will handle the vast majority of locators most people will ever need. The only thing they won't handle is locating an element by contained text but if it's an A tag, you can use link text.

Comment: @becixb there is also some additional motivation [here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/style-guide#never-use-xpath).

Comment: Yeah... but that's overly dramatic. XPath isn't any more brittle or require any more maintenance than an equally crafted CSS selector. They aren't unreadable if you know how to read them. Someone could just as easily claim the same about CSS selectors if they didn't know the syntax either (having said that, the CSS selector syntax is simpler but it's also less powerful). I'd love to see him translate that crazy complicated XPath into the equivalent CSS selector, if it's even possible. It wouldn't look too appealing either. XPath has it's uses. There's some things no other locator can do.

Comment: @JeffC absolutely, it has its own use cases, no argument there.

Comment: @alecxe that is some very badly written xpath. they put that in there because they know how ugly it is. show me the html and what they're looking for and I'll create a beauty. they're using xpath for node counts but why not use it similar to how they use css locators? ayayay google testers. i wonder why...